# Bootstrap and body padding left and right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries, padding

I am using Bootstrap to create a responsive web page. I need to add a **padding-left and padding-right to the body** to always have a 50px wide >empty safety area< on each side.
Problem: When I resize the viewport, the content of container overflow on the right.

Is there a simple way how to achieve this effect? I only tried the following one, but it doesn't look very good (the container is too narrow in the end).

```
// container responsivity fix
.container {
  .container-fixed();

  @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    width: calc(~'@{container-sm} - 100px');
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
    width: calc(~'@{container-md} - 80px');
  }
  @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) {
    width: calc(~'@{container-lg} - 100px');
  }
}
```

HTML structure:

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
        <a href="#">
          LOGO
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong> consectetur adipiscing elit.</strong> </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 text-right">
        <i class="flag cz active">A</i>
        <i class="flag uk">B</i>
        <i class="flag ge">C</i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o5bkpv7c/

Comment: Use `margin` on the body instead?

Comment: Well, have u tried that? I have even before - and it's not working.

Comment: That's because the text is too large. You can either size it down or break word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text is not stretchy so it won't fit inside the header past a certain breakpoint. I usually use break word or just size the text down or use fitText.js. There's cleaner ways of doing this.

### DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/o5bkpv7c/4/

```
body {
    padding: 0 20px;
}
header {
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 1em 0; 
}

header h2 {font-size:1.2rem;margin:10px 0;}


.flag {
    width: 29px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red; 
}

@media (min-width:768px) {
    
    header h2 {font-size:1.3rem;margin:0;}

}
```

Also, see the layout you are going for, I wouldn't use the grid system for it. Here's a cleaner way.

### http://jsbin.com/tuyeta/1/edit

Comment: Hi, this behaviour is cleaner, only when I tried it, my solution with columns behaved nicer when changing the viewport size. But thanks for the solution anyway!